# tkinter - Build single canvas item from lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating program that allows user to draw polyhedron. So I have to store creates edges (lines) in a list. Notice: lines do not form a cycle, but some of them have same vertex. I want to create a single canvas item from the list of lines (I have their start and end position), so I can bind mouse clicks to this object and make it draggable for user. However, `create_polygon` method requires cycled-styled list of lines (the next line have to begin from the ending of current). So I **can't** simply do like this (if there is no [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)):

```
cube_edges = [[(0, 0), (0, 3)], [(0, 0), (1, 1)], [(0, 3), (1, 4)], [(1, 1), (1, 4)],
              [(0, 0), (3, 0)], [(3, 0), (4, 1)], [(3, 0), (3, 3)], [(0, 3), (3, 3)],
              [(3, 3), (4, 4)], [(1, 4), (4, 4)], [(4, 1), (4, 4)], [(1, 1), (4, 1)]]
vertex = list()
for start, end in cube_edges:
    if start not in vertex:
        vertex.append(start)
    if end not in vertex:
        vertex.append(end)
canvas.create_polygon(*vertex)
```

So is there any way to unite multiple objects (lines) as one item?

Comment: There's no way of grouping multiple objects as a single canvas item.  However, many Canvas methods will work on multiple items simultaneously if they all share a tag (which is just a string, that isn't entirely composed of digits).  You could auto-generate tags for each user-drawn polyhedron as "tag1", "tag2", etc.

Comment: @jasonharper
Currently I use tag "draggable" for all drawn items and bind "<ButtonPress-1>" to the items with this tag. So if I click and move one edge, how the programm will move other?

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you. Eventually i found method canvas.gettags(item).  So I can get item_tag from only one edge. And manipulate other edges with canvas.move(item_tag, x, y)

Comment: Dmitry: Here's documentation on the [Methods on Canvas widgets](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/canvas-methods.html) have and there are many that deal with tags (which you may find useful).

Answer (score 2):

You can give all of the lines for a single object the same tag. When dragging the object, move all objects with the same tag.

For example, give each set of lines a tag like "line1", "line2", etc. when a user clicks on a canvas object, get the tags for that object with `canvas.gettags(id)`, and from that find the tag that begins with "line". Then, when calling `canvas.move`, pass in that tag.